# Can the System Drive Be Spun Down After Certain Idle Time?

Tags: server, hard-drive, power-management

I am trying to spin down my HDD after a certain amount of idle time to save power since I am running Ubuntu Server on a laptop. I know that it is possible to spin down additional drives, but according to this [article](http://www.havetheknowhow.com/Configure-the-server/Spin-down-idle-drives.html), the system drive cannot be spun down. This kind of makes sense to me, being that the system is running off that drive, but I don't know. Is there a way to spin down the system drive? Would it be unwise to do so?

Comment: From what I understand, when the system is booted, it's loaded to ram, with only additional reads to the HDD being to update information, look at files, etc. That being said, spinning the HDD down probably won't save much power, but that's just my personal opinion, as I haven't noticed a difference in battery life between having an ssd and an HDD, and if so it was negligible.

Comment: I see, thank you. Would spinning it down improve it's life span or offer any other benefits at all?

Comment: it could potentially increase. The lifespan, but again, it's only read from when needed, so it might be negligible. We should wait for a more experienced user to weigh in, though.

Comment: I see. I did a bit of research, from what I can tell, there are not really any benefits. My system seems to be drawing only ~10 W anyway, most of it from the network card. Cycling the drive can actually wear it out more quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a bit of research, from what I can tell, there are not really any benefits. My system seems to be drawing only ~10 W anyway, most of it from the network card. Cycling the drive can actually wear it out more quickly. I suppose if you are running actual server hardware with a vast number of drives, then it is actually worthwhile.